# Can't access or get session Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Codeigniter Can't access or get session

this function use for set session

```
function checkuser($password){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $result = $this->login->login($username,$password);
    if($result){

            $sess_array = $arrayName = array('id' => '01', 'username' => $username, 'fullname' => 'alex xer');
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            redirect(base_url('index.php/home'), 'refresh');

    } else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkuser', 'Invalid username or password');
        return false;
    }
}
```

### ----------------

This function use for get session but always else why I can't get it.

```
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
        $data['fullname'] = $session_data['fullname'];
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
        $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
    } else{
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added the session global?
`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

Comment: ah alreay it's already     $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'session');

Comment: I don't know about problem

Comment: Try setting the  `logged_in` option as one of the elements in the `$sess_array` then retrieve it accordingly

Comment: Make sure you have set your session save path in config.php

Comment: it's not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 $sess_array = $arrayName = array('id' => '01', 'username' => $username, 'fullname' => 'alex xer');
$this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);

redirect(base_url('home'), 'refresh');
```

and than

```
{
    if($this->session->userdata('id')){
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
        $data['fullname'] = $session_data['fullname'];
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
        $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
    } else{
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

I hope this will be help you :)